# CSS3: Is it possible to have thousands separator in numbers?

Tags: css, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting numbers (decimal places, thousands separators, etc) with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-etc-with-css)

I'm working on a web application for statistics (LAMP platform), and I was wondering if CSS3 could take care of thousands separation in numbers.

For example, I would like that a writing just like

```
Items sold: 101715
```

could appear like

```
Items sold: 101 715
```

So with a space as a thousands separator.

I know I can have it with PHP, and also that for something like CSS3 this has to do with semantic evaluation of related content, but I started wondering if this could be possible.

Anyone?

Comment: **Javascript:** [`(1234567).toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) formats the number with commas/dots/spaces/etc as required for the client's browser locale setting.... or, force a specific format by specifying locale.  For example, `(1234567).toLocaleString('en-CA')` returns `"1,234,567"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No CSS cant format numbers, if you would like to do something like that in the client, you would have to look into javascript.