# Format the display of a field

Tags: html, css, number-formatting

[I'm aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372624) that parsing numbers with pure CSS is impossible. But as in my case I know for certain that the input will always be in a specific way, is it possible to change the display of an input field based on the count of characters in it?

e.G. I want '123450' to be displayed as '1,234.50' - or if it were 'abcdef' it should become 'a,bcd.ef'.

So, I would like a rule that says: from right to left: after the second char display a dot, after the fifth and eight char display a comma.

Is that possible?

Example:

```
<input type="text" class="unformatted" value="123456" />
```

Should display like

```
<input type="text" class="formatted" vaulue="1,234.56" />
```

while still retaining its original value 123456.

Comment: The input should be editable and should it still retain the value unformatted?

Comment: @fcalderan If at all possible, yes. If not then I have to parse the input on the receiving end which complicates matters.

Comment: https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ take a look at "numeral formatting" section

Comment: @fcalderan I'm looking for a CSS Solution, doing this in JS is already documented in the linked question.

Comment: in CSS it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible with pure CSS. The smallest you can go with CSS is the single HTML tag, you cannot go *deeper* than that.
Individual lines of text cannot be selected or altered, as they are seen as a whole by CSS engine.

With a little help from JavaScript, however, this can be easily done.