# More efficient way to format currency values

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

I would like to display `decimal` numbers as USD currency within HTML pages. For example, display 1209.27 as **$1,209 <sup>27</sup>**.

Instead of using `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` in the models, I format each number directly in the view:

```
@Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Price), "(?<=\\.)([^.]*$)", "<sup>&nbsp;$1</sup>"), "\\.<sup>", "<sup>"))
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this format instead of repeating this all over?

Comment: I'd consider a CSS solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372624/formatting-a-number-as-currency-using-css

Comment: Nice CSS/JS alternative. To minimize JS, I opted for a custom `HtmlHelper`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider writing a Razor DisplayTemplate or a [custom html helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to style as you wish.

```
<style type="text/css">
.price { font-weight: bold;}
.currency {}
.decimals { font-size: 0.6em; font-weight: normal; vertical-align: baseline; top: -0.4em; position: relative; }
</style>
This item costs 
<span class="price">
<span class="currency">$</span>5,310<span class="decimals">.79</span></span> Dollars.
```

working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/a3vksgcu/1/

Original solution here:
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/solved-a-more-interesting-price-display-using-css/