# CSS - 10000 presented as 10 000?

Tags: css, number-formatting

**Users search for "10000" in Google**

I write about loan costs and for me my positions in Google are important. I might rank at keywords like "Loan 10000".

**Users like to read "10 000" in content**

However for users when they read, it looks better like this: "Loan 10 000 SEK".

**Number format in CSS or SEO-friendly workaround?**

Is there a way in CSS we can add a space between numbers in CSS?

Comment: I don't think Google cares whether there's a space there or not. I get results with spaces, no spaces, commas and full stops when [searching for 10000](http://google.com/search?q=10000).

Comment: you can use the :after selector, although I'm not too sure how you would implement it to get the results you want in your circumstance to get.

Comment: Read http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting

Comment: Currently there is no way to format a number through CSS alone. You might just present th number formatted, because as stated above, Google will most likely read it nonetheless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting numbers (decimal places, thousands separators, localization, etc) with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-localization-etc-wit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dirty SEO trick: putting plain "10000" in your page and replace it to "10 000" via javascript when it's displayed.

This way robots are more likely to index your "10000" while your users will see "10 000". I know taht your request implies CSS only, but I see no other workaround for what you want.

Comment: As there is no real solution with CSS I think this is the best alternative. Simple and even if the user has javascript disabled will at least see "10000" instead of "10 000"

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in CSS without modifying markup. Using modified markup like

```
<span class=grp>100</span>000
```

you could use CSS for spacing:

```
.grp { padding-right: 0.2em; } /* or maybe a little smaller */
```

Search engines may get disturbed by inline markup so that they would not recognize this as the same as 100000 at the text level. But there does not seem to be much hard evidence on this.

I would not do this in CSS, since it is a matter cultural norms and conventions, not styling preferences. For languages that use a space as thousands separator, I would just use `10&nbsp;000`.