# Adding commas in Javascript Countup

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript

```
<script>
var START_DATE = new Date("February 21, 2018 00:00:00"); // put in the 
starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 6720; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 17419171608; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

window.onload = function()
{
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
 setInterval("count += INCREMENT; 
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
</script>
```

I am trying to put commas to separate the thousands in the above code but I have been unable to do so.

I tried the instructions [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/javascript-countup-with-commas/73546), but I have not been able to put the commas separating the thousands.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-etc-with-css#answer-28708770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your example and i modifed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
 
            var START_DATE = new Date("December 1, 2010 20:00:00"); // put in the starting date here
            var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
            var INCREMENT = 1; // increase per tick
            var START_VALUE = 4166667; // initial value when it's the start date
            var count = 0;
 
            window.onload = function() {
                var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
                var now = new Date();
                count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count.toString());
                setInterval(incrCount, msInterval);
            }
 
            function incrCount() {
                count += INCREMENT;
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count.toString());
            }
 
           
   
   function addCommas(nStr){
                return parseInt(nStr).toLocaleString();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <div id="counter"></div>
 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks Jesus Cuesta. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Number.prototype.toLocaleString() function on your "count" variable.  The number will be printed depending on the locale, so for EN it will have the expected commas.

```
var count = 10000000;    
console.log (count.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, harymitchell; but I am afraid that did not make any change.

Comment: Like in the accepted answer, you would actually have the use the function in your code.  What I show is just example usage.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

There is a great function for parsing negative,large and floats.

You can try outputting your count after running it through this:

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return parts.join(".");
}
```

Here is a quick fiddle i through together to show you the method:
https://jsfiddle.net/r4s5rrrn/2/