# How to round decimal places in css

Tags: html, css

I have a table in html. I want to round cell content to 2 decimal digits only.

```html
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Laptop</td>
                <td>2000.0000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile</td>
                <td>1000.0000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have option to use CSS only. Is that possible in CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting numbers (decimal places, thousands separators, etc) with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-etc-with-css)

Comment: Why do you have the option for only using CSS? You should be using Javascript for this.

Comment: CSS is probably the worst way to approach this, but I'm going to assume that you have no access to the HTML

Comment: HTML file is getting generated dynamically using powersheel. i would try to put external javascript file.

Comment: What does "i would try to put javascript external file" mean?

Comment: If you're going to generate the HTML dynamically, do your fixed decimal point output when you generate the HTML

Comment: I will add javascript file along with css file too. but i was looking if something is available now to achieve same in  CSS.

Answer (score -2):

Using jQuery it would be something like this, assuming each cell containing a number had the `number` class:

```
$('tr.number').each( function () {
    // get value of table cell and convert to number...
    var val = parseFloat($(this).text());
    // put it back as fixed point value
    $(this).text(val.toFixed(2));
});
```