Dash input number with thousand separator
I have doing a simple Dash application, and I have one component to get the input from the User as an integer.
The issue is that the integer should be between 1,000,000 and 1,000,000,000. So for an easy way to read it, I would love to display the thousand separated by comma instead of 1000000 or 1000000000.
Currently the workaround I found is to replace my dcc.Input number:
dcc.Input(id='input', type='number', value=1000000, min=1000000, max=1000000000)

by a dcc.Input string :
 dcc.Input(id='input', type='text', value='1,000,000')

main issue is that when the user enter the number, I have to manage a lot of potential issue (he didn't put a number, I have to clean the comma and cast the string to int), so it is a lot of exception on the callback side to handle, and potentially a lot of bug.
I just would like to know if it is possible to keep the Number as input type AND having a display comma separated ?
Thanks

Related: https://community.plotly.com/t/thousand-separator-for-dcc-input/29563

yes I found that but it was in 2019 and according to the answer not possible to do it, so as it is 5 years ago I try to ask in case some solution has been found

Here is what I did:
Add the following file: assets/script.js (if the assets folder is missing, create it)
// convert from a string like "1,000,000" to the integer 1000000
function unformattedValue(input) {
    return parseInt(input.replace(/,/g, ""));
}

// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-localization-etc-wit
function formatNumberInput(input) {     
    // When user select text in the document, also abort.
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString(); 
    if (selection !== '') {
        return; 
    }       
    // Get the value.
    input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); 
    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0; 
    return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
}

Then use clientside_callback, and change 'input' to be the id of the element you want to have digit separators. In this case, you are using the id 'input', so you don't have to change anything. Make sure that the input is has type='text'
clientside_callback(
    """function(stringValue) {
        const value = unformattedValue(stringValue);
        
        // do whatever with value here
        setTimeout(() => alert("value+1000=" + (value+1000)), 0);

        return formatNumberInput(stringValue);
    }""",
    Output('input', 'value'),
    Input('input', 'value')
)

main.py:
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Output, Input, clientside_callback
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children='Title of Dash App', style={'textAlign':'center'}),
    dcc.Input(id='input', type='text', value="1,000,000")
])

clientside_callback(
    """function(stringValue) {
        const value = unformattedValue(stringValue);
        
        // do whatever with value here
        setTimeout(() => alert("value+1000=" + (value+1000)), 0);

        return formatNumberInput(stringValue);
    }""",
    Output('input', 'value'),
    Input('input', 'value')
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

For converting from the string format into a usable integer
def unformatted_value(input):
    return int(input.replace(",", ""))

function unformattedValue(input) {
    return parseInt(input.replace(/,/g, ""));
}


I have already a version working with input as text, my idea would be to do the reverse : having an input as int, receive an int into the callback also, but having the possibility to display the number with comma in the front

@kilag I have updated my answer to indicate how you might achieve something similar :)

You can acheive this using this code:
`
number = 1000000000
formatted_number = "{:,}".format(number)
print(formatted_number)

`
Also, if you need to display the number in code with seperation, use '_'. Eg: 100_000_000. the _ will be ignored
if you want to convert the string to int, use this
int('100,000,000'.replace(",", ""))


I thin OP doesn't want to display it but OP gets string like '1,000,000' and OP want to convert it to integer value.

that can be done by int('100,000,000'.replace(",", ""))

you can write it in answer, not in comment.
